# MySQL Select show specific column values first

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a table with about 3 million rows that consists of cities, the countries in which the city lies and some other data.

I want to retrieve for example limited rows where the name of the city starts with a certain string but list those that lie in a specific country first.

I tried to order them by *country <> "us"* which is very slow as the server has to sort all found rows before applying the limit.

Now I came up with the following statement:

```
(SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city LIKE "ab%" AND country = "at" LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city LIKE "ab%" LIMIT 5)
LIMIT 5
```

It is very fast with any prefix length but it looks kinda dirty.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I think that's as good as it gets.

Comment: I don't follow the logic of the query.  Also, why are you applying `LIMIT 5` to the outside when you are already having only 10 records?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Because he only wants 5 rows in the final result. If there are less than 5 rows from `at`, he wants to fill the remaining slots from other countries.

Comment: Great analysis, I would not have figured this out.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As Barmar said, because I only want 5 rows as a result. I could do that manually after i got the result which has at most 10 rows, but I think the server does that a bit faster and I would save a little bandwidth. Yet it does not really matter.

Comment: @Barmar After using EXPLAIN I noticed that mysql uses the indexes very efficiently and somehow combining both SELECT statements into one. It just looks really ugly and desperate.

Comment: What does EXPLAIN say if you use `ORDER BY country = 'at' DESC LIMIT 5` in the regular query?

Comment: @Barmar It's using filesort on the country column. Seems there is too much data. It makes it very, very slow with a short prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 5 *
, case when country = 'ab' then 1 
  else 0 end as rnk 
from cities
where lower(city) like 'ab%' 
or country = 'ab'
order by rnk desc;
```

Comment: This is not MySQL. Anyway, this query still needs the server to sort the result which again, is really slow with so many rows in the table.